# parsing xml file and displaying the content using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile environment. I have an XML file and I need to parse it and display the content using JqueryMobile.

this is the format of XML:

```
<Result>
  <Details>
    <Attendee>
      <AttendeeID>1</AttendeeID>
      <Name>krishna</Name>
      <AttendeeEmail>kri@gmail.com</AttendeeEmail>
      <AttendeeMobile>9876543210</AttendeeMobile>
      <AttendeeProfession>Android</AttendeeProfession>
      <AttendeeTagCloud>Developers</AttendeeTagCloud>
    </Attendee>
    <Response>Success</Response>
    <Count>1</Count>
  </Details>
</Result>
```

I tried Google-ing it but couldn't find anything that would help me out.

Kindly help me solve this.I am not able to solve the xml tags

Comment: I see a lot of useful information when Googling `jquery mobile parse xml`

Comment: I am getting only stackoverflow links

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885962/jquery-parse-xml) - I'm getting SO links too, **with the exact same question, *answered***. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.parseXML`

```
 xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $email= $xml.find( "AttendeeEmail" ).text();

alert($email);
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WPV9B/**

Comment: :My xml resides in a remote server, so how do I retrieve the remote xml file and then parse it using jquery mobile

Comment: make a web service(that allows `CORS(cross-origin-resourse-sharing)`) on the server that when queried return a xml response, query that service using `ajax` and parse it

Comment: also keep in mind the `same-origin-policy` you can use `jsonp` etc

Comment: i have services already running and I have a url which responds me with above xml file, I am little confused to use the url to get the xml file and parse it

Comment: I was not do that now I am getting  in the error bug which says " Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: @3nigma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2730/discussion-between-jeevan-dongre-and-3nigma)

Comment: @Jeevan Dongre  i went out, the reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to access the server that is out side your domain, can you edit your question or make a new one with sample code that you are using to access the service

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to pull a remote xml that is dynamically rendered on my web server.

**Code that retrieves the xml file from server:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

       $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "YOUR URL TO THE XML FILE ON THE SERVER",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: parseXml
               });
```

**Code that parses the xml file in jquery mobile:**

```
function parseXml(xml) {
$(xml).find('YOUR XML RECORD NODE FIELD').each(function(){
                  $("YOUR DIV ID/CLASS IN YOUR JQUERY MOBILE PAGE").append('SOME HTML CODE LIKE <li><h3>') + $(this).find("FIELD TO DISPLAY FROM YOUR XML RECORD").text() + 'CLOSING HTML CODE FROM ABOVE </h3></li>');
 });
}
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps.